# .NET/C#: NullReferenceException inside Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand when calling stored procedure with IN OUT parameters

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

Using the following stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure sp_param_test(p_1 number, p_2 in out number) as
begin
    p_2 := p_2 * 2;
end;
```

And the following C# code:

```
    using var connection = new OracleConnection("Data Source=localhost/ORCL;User ID=...");
    connection.Open();
    using var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "call sp_param_test(:p_1, :p_2)";
    
    var p_2 = command.CreateParameter();
    p_2.ParameterName = "p_2";
    p_2.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
    p_2.Value = 123;
    command.Parameters.Add(p_2);

    var p_1 = command.CreateParameter();
    p_1.ParameterName = "p_1";
    p_1.Value = 0;
    command.Parameters.Add(p_1);
    
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    var value = p_2.Value;
    connection.Close();
```

A NullReferenceException is thrown by ExecuteNonQuery. If the parameter is changed to an input-only parameter (remove the "IN OUT" specification) and parameter direction removed from C#, the call works.

The reason the first parameter is unused is I'm trying to call the procedure using named parameter (eg. "p_1 => :p1") but before I can do that I need to resolve the null reference issue.

Anyone seen this behavior before? (using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core version 2.19.100)

BTW. Using CommandType = StoredProcedure works, but the order of parameters needs to be known by the .NET code (the thing I'm trying to avoid). The parameter names are ignored and only the order of calls to Parameters.Add is used to construct the call)

Comment: *"the order of parameters needs to be known by the .NET code"* - set `command.BindByName = true;` and that won't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks @madreflection that makes the workaround using CommandType = StoredProcedure work! I'll implement using that unless I find out what's causing the NullRef later on.